# how do I get angular2 dependency injection to work with value providers

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

I'm following the angular docs for Dependency Injection and tried to duplication the section on  [dependency injection tokens](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#dependency-injection-tokens). But it's clear I still don't get it.

I'm trying to use a `value provider` to inject an `config:any` into my project.

At the simplest level, I just want to `provide` a const string

```
// app-modules.ts
const CFG_STRING = "I was declared externally and injected in ngModule"    
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  providers: [
    {provide: CFG_STRING, useValue: CFG_STRING}
  ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

and `inject` into a Component constructor

```
// app.ts
const LOCAL_STRING = "I was declared in the local module"
export class App {
  constructor(
    // @Optional() cfgString: CFG_STRING
  ) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.local = LOCAL_STRING

    /* provided/injected */
    // this.injectedStr = cfgString
  }
}
```

But when I do so the app doesn't run correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/sQwxyDqLkMTgVUjJ1yYF?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use a type as key for the provider but instead a string or `OpaqueToken` you need to pass the key to `@Inject()`

```
constructor(
    @Inject('CFG_STRING') /* @Optional()*/ cfgString: CFG_STRING
  ) {
```

and provide it like

```
  providers: [
    {provide: 'CFG_STRING', useValue: CFG_STRING}
  ],
```

`CFG_STRING` is not a type and can therefore not be used as key. Either you use some string or mentioned an `OpaqueToken`. It can be any string, it just needs to match between `provide` and `@Inject()`

Comment: This is so awesome. why do I waste so many hours trying to RTFM when I can just ask on stackoverflow?!?? BTW, the angular.io cheatsheet does not pass the key as a string, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html

Comment: If you use a type, then you don't need to, but `CFG_STRING` is not a type, it's a string constant. `MyValue` in `{ provide: MyValue, useValue: 41 }` has to be a type though.

Comment: what kind of Type would MyValue be to accept a number as the `useValue`?  `let MyValue: number` did not work

Comment: The constructor parameter would need to be `number` but you can then use `constructor(@Inject(MyValue) private myValue:number)`

Comment: I mean, what is an example of `MyValue` in ` { provide: MyValue, useValue: 41 }` where `MyValue` is a Type and can accept a number as an assignment?

Comment: I don't think there is another type than `number` where you can assign `41` to, but maybe there are some TS tricks that allow you to do that. I don't have deep TS knowledge. I use only Dart with Angular2.