# How to make a string constant in angular 4?

Tags: angular

In my service, I am using a `http` post. I want to set the URL as a constant.

```
return this.http.get(this.config.API_URL+'users', options).map(res=>res.json());
```

I tried with a service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  API_URL :String;

  constructor() {
    this.API_URL = 'some url';
  }
}
```

Is there any other method to make a constant value in Angular4 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define global constants in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986922/define-global-constants-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand your question but if you want to create constants, you can do it in a different class and import it.

constants.ts

```
export class Constants {
  public static get HOME_URL(): string { return "sample/url/"; };
}
```

sample.component.ts

```
   import { Constants } from "./constants";
    @Component({

    })
     export class SampleComponent {
      constructor() {
       let url = Constants.HOME_URL;
      }
    }
```

Comment: how to call like this? `const USER_AUTH_API_URL = '/api-url';`

Answer (score 34):

You can simply export a constant using es6/typescript modules if that's all you need:

constants.ts:

```
export const API_URL: string = 'api/url';
```

And import where needed:

```
import { API_URL } from './constants.ts';

...

return this.http.get(API_URL+'users', options)
                .map(res=>res.json());
```

or if you have many constants you can import them all:

```
import * as constants from './constants.ts';

...

return this.http.get(constants.API_URL+'users', options)
                    .map(res=>res.json());
```

If you want to make your constants configurable per application on startup, you can use providers. Check out the top answer in this link: [how do I get angular2 dependency injection to work with value providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344266/how-do-i-get-angular2-dependency-injection-to-work-with-value-providers)

Comment: If the constant happens to be an object, you can wrap it in a `Object.freeze({ ... })`` to make it a real constant.

Answer (score 4):

Define app constant as public static readonly as below

> public static readonly constName = 'Consts Value'

*/app-constants.ts*

```
export class Constants {

     public static readonly routeAuthRegister = '/auth/register';
     public static readonly routeAuthLogin = '/auth/login';
     public static readonly routeAuthRecovery = '/auth/forgot-password';

}
```

*/api-constants.ts*

> It's better to keep your base URI's in enverment files. and define your environments in apps in .angular-cli.json. i here attache screen shot below for define custom app environments .

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

export class ApiURIs {

    public static readonly apiURL: string = environment.apiEndpoint;
    public static readonly apiV1: string = environment.apiEndpoint + '/v1';
    public static readonly apiV2: string = environment.apiEndpoint + '/v2';


    public static readonly login: string = ApiEndpoints.apiV1 + '/login';
    public static readonly register: string = ApiEndpoints.apiV1 + '/register';
    public static readonly signup: string = ApiEndpoints.apiV2 + '/register';

}
```

**Usage of constants**

*/core/auth.service.ts*

```
import { ApiURIs } from './api-constants';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    .....

    signUpUser(data) {
        return this.https.post(`${ApiURIs.signup}`, data);
    }

    .....
}
```

*/auth/login.component.ts*

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   .....

   navigateToForgotPassowrd() {

        this.router.navigate([Constants.routeAuthRecovery]);
   }
   ......
}
```

Define your different API URI's for different environment

[image: environments file & .angular-cli.json]